# Can't figure out what the generic name of this algorithm is called?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic, combinations, permutation

I just did a Top Coder SRM where there was a question I had problem solving. I am trying to searching online for details of the algorithm but I can't seem to find it.

The question went around the lines of:
You have an array, for example [12, 10, 4]

Each round, you can apply any permutation of 9,3,1 to subtract from [12,10,4]

Return the minimum amount of permutations needed to be applied to get to 0 for all numbers in the array.

Any help?

Edit: Let me be somewhat more descriptive so that the question can be understood better.

```
One question would be
input: [12 10 4]
output: 2 (minimum rounds)

How it would work:
[12 10 4] - [9 3 1] = [3 7 3]
[12 10 4] - [9 1 3] = [3 9 1]
[12 10 4] - [3 9 1] = ..
[12 10 4] - [3 1 9] = ..
[12 10 4] - [1 3 9] =
[12 10 4] - [1 9 3] =

[3 7 3] - [3 9 1] = ...

..
[9 1 3] - [9 1 3] = [0 0 0] <-- achieved with only two permutation subtractions
```

Edit2:

Here is the topcoder question:
http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13782

Edit3:
Can anyone also explain the Overlapping Subproblem and Optimal Substructure if they believe a solution is with dynamic programming?

Comment: Right, after working it out on paper (clearly I can't do it in my head!), you mean that something like [12, 10, 4] - [3, 9, 1] = [9, 1, 3] - [9, 1, 3] = [0, 0, 0]?

Comment: what do you mean be "minimum amount of permutations"? for your example what's the answer?

Comment: I don't think there's a classic algorithm dedicated to solving this problem. Interesting question though, what are the maximum lengths of your arrays?

Comment: What is the maximum size of the array?

Comment: Could you link to the problem?

Comment: I take it it's this problem: http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13782

Comment: Thanks, yes that's it! This morning it wasn't showing up on the archive.

Comment: I don't think your problem has a common name. However, the approach you are using looks like "*dynamic programming*" or "*backtracking*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT :

**after seeing the original question, here is the solution which gave correct output for every testcase provided in above question link, if u want give input {60} , u shud give as {60,0,0} .**

Basic idea is , u need to get all of them less than or equal to zero atlast , so if number is divisible by 3 , u can get zero by subtracting 9 or 3 and if not divisible, subtract by 1 to make it divisible by 3

first , sort the given triplet , then

- check the largest number is divisible by 3, if so, subtract 9 and the number still can be divisible by 3
- now check the next largest number , if it is divisible by 3, subtract 3 else subtract 1
- if largest number is not divisible by 3, subtract 1 so that it may be divisible by 3
- now subtract next largest number by 9 and the other one by 3

here is the implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int f(int* a,int k){
sort(a,a+3);
if(a[2]<=0 )
{cout << k<< endl ;
return 0;}

if(a[1]<=0){
cout << k+ceil((double)a[2]/9) << endl;
return 0;

}
if(a[2]%3==0 ){
a[2]=a[2]-9;
if(a[1]%3==0 )
{
    a[1] = a[1] -3;
    a[0] = a[0] -1;
}
else{
    if(a[2]%2==0 && (a[1]-1)%2==0  && a[1]!=0){
        a[2]=a[2] +9 -3;
        a[1] = a[1] -9;
        a[0] = a[0]-1;
    }
    else{
    a[1] = a[1] -1;
    a[0] = a[0] - 3;}
}
return f(a,++k);
}
else{
a[2] = a[2] -1;

    a[1] = a[1] -9;
    a[0]=a[0] -3;
return f(a,++k);

}
}
int main() {

int a[] = {54,18,6};
f(a,0);
return 0;
}
```

hope this is helpful

**Example:**
input is `[12,4,10]`

sort it `[12,4,10] -> [12,10,4]`

now check if largest number is divisible by `3`, here `Yes`

so
`[12-9,10,4] -> [3,10,4]`
now check next largest number divisible by `3`, here `N0`

so
`[3,10-1,4-3] ->[3,9,1]`

now increment count and pass this to function `(recursive)`

input -> `[3,9,1]`

sort `[3,9,1] -> [9,3,1]`

now check if largest number is divisible by `3`, here `Yes`

so `[9-9,3,1] -> [0,3,1]`

now check next largest number divisible by `3`, here `Yes`

so `[0,3-3,1-1] -> [0,0,0]`

now increment the count and pass the array

as largest element is `0` , we will print count and that is `2`

Comment: Then I don't understand your algorithm. Show an example of how it will work given the initial array `[12,10,4]`. Show each step.

Comment: @JimMischel , 10 is not divisible by 3 so i subtract 1 , so it becomes [12,10,4] - [9,1,3] = [3,9,1]  , pls consider looking at the code, i ran the code and got output 2

Comment: Hmmmm ... interesting algorithm. Can you prove that it works in all cases?

Comment: @JimMischel, if the result can be made [0,0,0] then it will work sir, else i need to extend it sir, but according to question , this is enough sir

Comment: I'm not so sure. Given `[15,13,11]`, your algorithm subtracts `[9,1,3]` giving `[6,12,8]`. Sort to `[12,8,6]` and subtract (again, by your algorithm) `[9,1,3]`, and you end up with `[3,7,3]`, which is a dead end. But if you start with `[15,13,11]`, subtract `[3,9,1]` to give `[12,4,10]`, then it's solvable.

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks sir, i will edit it adding cases which u said above sir

Comment: Editted the solution according to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of elements be `n`, let p<sub>1</sub> to p<sub>n!</sub> be the permutations of the array you want to subtract, and let A be your original array. Then you want the natural numbers solutions of the linear system

A - k<sub>1</sub>*p<sub>1</sub> - ... - k<sub>n!</sub>*p<sub>n!</sub> = 0

which is equivalent to

A = k<sub>1</sub>*p<sub>1</sub> + ... + k<sub>n!</sub>*p<sub>n!</sub>

where `0` is the `n`-item array with all zeroes. You can't figure that out using the obvious linear algebra solution since `ℕ^n` is not an `ℕ`-vector space; actually, finding solutions to linear systems over natural numbers in general is [NP-complete by a reduction from subset sum](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26206/what-algorithms-exist-for-solving-natural-number-linear-systems). I couldn't adapt the reduction to your version of the problem ad hoc, so maybe think about that for a bit. It should remain NP-hard, at least that's what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved using dynamic programming. If you look at common solutions to dynamic programming problems, they follow the same general structure. We use an array to store the minimum number of permutations needed to reach each value, and update each value in turn using nested loops. The answer will end up in `d[0][0][0]` which is the number of permutations required to get to [0, 0, 0].

```
public static int count(int a, int b, int c) {
    int[][] permutations = {{9, 3, 1}, {9, 1, 3}, {1, 9, 3}, {1, 3, 9}, {3, 9, 1}, {3, 1, 9}};

    int[][][] d = new int[a + 1][b + 1][c + 1];

    // Set initial values to high value to represent no solution.
    for(int x = 0; x <= a; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y <= b; y++) {
            for(int z = 0; z <= c; z++) {
                d[x][y][z] = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // Set number of permutations for initial value to 0.
    d[a][b][c] = 0;

    // Update all values.
    for(int x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
        for(int y = b; y >= 0; y--) {
            for(int z = c; z >= 0; z--) {
                for(int[] p:permutations) {
                    // Update count from [x, y, z] -> [nx, ny, nz] using permutation p.
                    int nx = x - p[0];
                    int ny = y - p[1];
                    int nz = z - p[2];
                    if(nx >= 0 && ny >= 0 && nz >= 0) {
                        d[nx][ny][nz] = Math.min(d[nx][ny][nz], d[x][y][z] + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return final answer.
    return d[0][0][0];
}
```

Comment: Looking at the problem statement, some of the values can be less than 0, and the number of values in the array can vary. It should be easy to adapt the solution accordingly.

Comment: Hey fgb, If this can be solved using dynamic programming, can you explain what the Overlapping Subproblem and Optimal Substructure are? I'm aware that both are the properties of dynamic programming questions but it isn't clear to me what they are?

Comment: @McFlurriez It has overlapping subproblems because subtracting [9, 3, 1] then [9, 1, 3] is the same as subtracting [9, 1, 3] then [9, 3, 1]. You get the same subproblem either way. It has optimal substructure because if you have values with `n` minimum permutations, then subtracting one of the permutations will give you values with `n-1` minimum permutations. An instance of the problem can be reduced to a simpler version of the same problem.